# Parse a file in C/ add it to an array

Tags: c, file

I'm currently working on a project using RAW codes to send some infra red signals.
I have a text file containing raw codes that looks something like:

```
300
400
600
900 
[...]
```

And so on.
The thing is in order for me to send these signals I need to use a function that calls an array.

```
codes[]=...
```

I wanted to know how can I parse through the file and add them to in array? Is it doable?
I'm a newbie in C so any tips would be apreciated.

The file contains integer numbers. It would be a maximum of 350 lines.
Also, there are no negative numbers. Value range: 0 < value <35000 (aproximately)

Comment: Is the file binary or text?

Comment: Unfortunately your question is way too broad. If you don't yet know the basics of the C language, then please use standard resources to learn the language first: courses, tutorials and books.

Comment: What data type should the array `codes` have? What is the possible number range for your values? Is there a maximum number of values or is their number fixed? One possible way is to read the file line by line using `fgets` and to parse the numbers with `strtol`.

Comment: So the file just contains integer numbers. And there is a maximum number yes. It doesn't go above 350 lines.

Comment: I will look up @Bodo thanks

Comment: @TeofilSandu Please [edit] your question and add the requested information there instead of answering in comments.

Comment: Can there be negative numbers or only positive numbers? (To decide if you need `int` or `unsigned int`) What are the maximum and minimum values?

Comment: Edited in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For text files, you can use something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{    

    int array[1000];
    int c, i = 0;
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("infrared.txt", "r");
    if (file) {
        while (fscanf(file, "%d", &c)!=EOF)
            array[i++] = c;
        fclose(file);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comparing the return code of `fscanf` with `EOF` is not sufficient. You should check that it returns the expected number of converted values, i.e. `1` in your case. It will return `0` if the data cannot be converted according to the specified format and it will return `EOF` if the end of file was reached before converting the first value or detecting invalid data or if an error occurred while reading the file.